# Flushing 0 Outstanding Messages For Offset Commit

Tags: multithreading, java.util.concurrent, apache-kafka-connect, paho, java-threads

I am writing my own Mqtt connector for Kafka. I know Confluent has Mqtt connector , but it is not open-source , so I decided to write my own connector.I have a problem about sending messages to Kafka. I can get Mqtt messages but can't send into Kafka. Basically, when a message comes from Mqtt Broker `messageArrived` method triggered , I am adding message into `BlockingQueue` like this:

```
private final BlockingQueue<SourceRecord> queue= new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    log.info("Message arrived : " + message.toString());
    queue.add(new SourceRecord(null, null, kafkaTopic, null,
            Schema.STRING_SCHEMA, message.getId(),
            Schema.BYTES_SCHEMA, message.getPayload()));
    }
```

And this is my `poll` method:

```
@Override
public List<SourceRecord> poll() throws InterruptedException {
    List<SourceRecord> records = new ArrayList<SourceRecord>();
    records.add(queue.take());
    return records;
}
```

So, when I debug this code, the output as follows in console repeteadly:

```
[2019-03-13 17:45:37,113] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mqtt-connector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2019-03-13 17:45:40,385] INFO Message arrived : {"timestamp":1552488339305,"values":[{"id":"Simulation.Simulator.Temperature","v":1,"q":true,"t":1552488336813}]} (deneme.MqttSourceTask)
[2019-03-13 17:45:45,386] INFO Message arrived : {"timestamp":1552488344305,"values":[{"id":"Simulation.Simulator.Temperature","v":2,"q":true,"t":1552488341809}]} (deneme.MqttSourceTask)
[2019-03-13 17:45:48,204] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mqtt-connector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
```

It seems, Mqtt messages  come but can't send Kafka. These two methods work asynchronous by multiple threads.

When I write the `queue.hashCode()` to the console in both `poll` and `messageArrived` method, hashcode is different. It acts like seperate queue object. I don't understand why it is. What causes to this problem?

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Have you printed any messages in between?

Comment: Yes, I've printed the `queue.hashCode()` , and it is writing different values both methods. That's the point I don't understand. It acts like different objects.